# How do I get the total number of a particular day in a particular month/year?

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say i want to know the number of Mondays in February 2014.

I understand this will use the DateTime class, but would like to see some coding examples please.

Comment: we're  here to help, not do it for you. What approach have you tried and failed at?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, there are more than one Monday in Feb 2014.  Which do you want?

Comment: As I understand it, you want to know how much mondays there are in february 2014. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should help you as a start:

[How To: Get all Mondays in a given year in C#](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2007/08/27/how-to-get-all-mondays-in-a-given-year-in-c.aspx)

You just have to adapt it to use month/year instead of only year.

Solution that almost get what you want:

[List the First Monday of every month using C# and VB.NET](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/11/list-first-monday-of-every-month-using.html)

Answer (score 10):

```
static int NumberOfParticularDaysInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int totalDays = startDate.AddMonths(1).Subtract(startDate).Days;

    int answer = Enumerable.Range(1, totalDays)
        .Select(item => new DateTime(year, month, item))
        .Where(date => date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
        .Count();

    return answer;
}
```

...

```
int numberOfThursdays = NumberOfParticularDaysInMonth(2010, 9, DayOfWeek.Thursday);
```

Answer (score 4):

@Anthony has given a nice Linq solution, here is a more traditional implementation.

```
static int CountDayOfWeekInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
  int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month);
  int weekDayCount = 0;
  for (int day = 0; day < days; ++day)
  {
    weekDayCount += startDate.AddDays(day).DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek ? 1 : 0;        
  }
  return weekDayCount;
}
```

Used as follows

```
int numberOfThursdays = CountDayOfWeekInMonth(2014, 2, DayOfWeek.Thursday);
```

Comment: +1 .  That being said, I think `if (startDate.AddDays(day).DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek) weekDayCount++;` is more readable.  I don't like to use the `?` operator just to avoid an if statement, though avoiding an if-else or avoiding the need to create a temporary variable bothers me less.  Maybe I'm biased because I don't mind one-line if statements.

Comment: Good answer. You know you could cheat to boost this along. For example, once you've found the first dayOfWeek match, there's no need to simply "++" the day. You can += 6 within the loop, then the next ++ will already be the next dayOfWeek match. (Another reason to use the `if` statement favored by @Brian.)

Comment: @Anthony: Let's not worry about optimizations until there is a performance bottleneck.  Your proposal makes the code slightly more complicated for a benefit that has an incredibly low chance of actually mattering.

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate through the complete month while you can calculate it?

```
Public Function CountDayOfWeekInMonth(ByVal DateTargeted As Date, Optional ByVal StartingDay As DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) As Integer
    Dim dCountingDate As New DateTime(DateTargeted.Year, DateTargeted.Month, 1)
    Dim iDaysInMonth As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dCountingDate.Year, dCountingDate.Month)
    Dim iDaysToAdd As Integer = (7 + CType(StartingDay, Integer) - dCountingDate.DayOfWeek) Mod 7
    Dim iFirstStartingDay As Integer = dCountingDate.AddDays(iDaysToAdd).Day
    Return Math.Truncate((iDaysInMonth - iFirstStartingDay) / 7) + 1
End Function
```

Used as follow

```
Dim iResult as Integer = CountDayOfWeekInMonth(New DateTime(2012, 04, 30), DayOfWeek.Monday)
```